# input values aren't being stored in database, but options are getting read

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this in my blade:

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="slug">Slug</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="slug" name="slug"> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="item_type">Item Type</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="item_type" name="item_type">
                                    <option value="physical-goods">Physical Goods</option>
                                    <option value="digital-downloads">Digital Downloads</option>
                                    <option value="credits">Credits</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label for="order_mode">Order Mode</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="order_mode" name="order_mode">
                                    <option value="fcfs">First Come, First Serve</option>
                                    <option value="pre-selling">Pre-Selling</option>
                                    <option value="purchase-order">Purchase Order</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <label for="short_description">Short Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="short_description" rows="2"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <label for="description">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
```

and I have this in my ProductsController@Store:

```
            $product = Product::firstorCreate([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'slug' => $request->input('slug'),
            'item_type' => $request->get('item_type'),
            'order_mode' => $request->get('order_mode'),
            'short_description' => $request->input('short_description'),
            'description' => $request->input('description')
        ]);
```

my validation:

```
        $this->validate($request, [
        'name'              => '',
        'slug'              => '',
        'item_type'         => 'required',
        'order_mode'        => 'required',
        'short_description' => '',
        'description'       => ''
    ]);
```

and I get the error that name and slug is required but I typed something in the name and slug inputs.
When I tried to remove the require field, I got an error and it showed that all my inputs: name, slug, short description, and description are all blank. I have checked my blade and their name checks out so why is this happening?

EDIT:
now I have this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '' for key 'products_slug_unique' (SQL: insert into `products`
>   (`name`, `slug`, `store_id`, `item_type`, `order_mode`,
>   `short_description`, `description`, `created_by_id`, `uuid`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, ,
>   36bf3d40-8cb7-11e8-9f9e-5b6a2e94b49b, physical-goods, fcfs,
>   dfgdfgdfgdd, dfgdgdfgdfgdf, 36bc6160-8cb7-11e8-9381-8b8110d8adde,
>   4ba43e00-aaa2-11e8-ae40-8983e976b812, 2018-08-28 09:11:06, 2018-08-28
>   09:11:06))

because when I try to save, the name and slug is not required thus it is saved in the database, but the problem is, there is nothing saved. it is blank. so when I try to save again then it will give me this error because slug is unique

Comment: where is your validation code

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR I have edited and added my validation

Comment: add the name attribute for your `textarea`

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR still doesn't work

Comment: I did and the values that I type in text area appears in my database, but the values for my name and slug still doesn't appear

Comment: Have you added all these fields to your fillable fields on your model? Because if they are not they will be ignored by laravel thus leaving them empty

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your acceptance of request. Please try this :-

```
$product = Product::firstorCreate([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'slug' => $request->slug,
    'item_type' => $request->item_type,
    'order_mode' => $request->order_mode,
    'short_description' => $request->short_description,
    'description' => $request->description
]);
```

Comment: @eibersji What are the errors that you are getting?

Comment: @eibersji as per your error, you have set your slug column to be unique. So either type unique values for your name or drop unique key from your table to get it working (second is not good option)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using : input and get ?

```
'slug' => $request->input('slug'),
'item_type' => $request->get('item_type'),
```

Try to dd($request->all()) to see what is actually send by your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
         you can  use this  

 {!! Form::open([ 'route' => ['ProductsController@Store '], 'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}

  //on Controller   

    public function ProductsController@Store($request){
    $this->validate($request, [
            'name'              => 'required',
            'slug'              => 'required',
            'item_type'         => 'required',
            'order_mode'        => 'required',
            'short_description' => 'required',
            'description'       => 'required'
        ]);

    $product = Product::firstorCreate([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'slug' => $request->slug,
        'item_type' => $request->item_type,
        'order_mode' => $request->order_mode,
        'short_description' => $request->short_description,
        'description' => $request->description
    ]);

    }
```

Comment: you should change your route redirect it on your controller    or       create    route

Comment: no, that is not the error. because I set the name of my route to products.store
I have used it in many of my projects. it is not the error

Comment: you can use dd($request);

Answer (score 0):

I see there are 2 problems -

1. You missed name of textareas belonging to short_description and description. If you donot provide name then it could be impossible to form fields to accessed in PHP with particular key.
2. Problem in writing validation rule(second parameter passed in validation)

As per documentation your validation code should be like -

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'item_type'         => 'required',
   'order_mode'        => 'required',
]);
```

Putting only those fields which need to be validated

Answer (score 0):

My only problem is that,

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="slug" name="slug">
```

is my code, and I am missing a '/'

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="slug" name="slug"/>
```

when I added the '/' it worked :)

Comment: it's not a case, modern browsers even works if you miss the closing tag

Comment: that is what I just did and it worked. I followed every answer but that is the only thing that worked